# How to choose a 3d modeling software?

Tags: 3d, models

What should you be aware before making a choice?

Comment: -1. Your question needs to be much more specific. What features are you looking for? How much are you willing to pay? What will you use the software for? etc..

Comment: Most answers will fall into blender.

Comment: bummzack, the question is not specific. This doesn't justify a downvote. Reinterpret it.

Comment: Overly broad is a [reason for closing questions](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#close) actually. Generally, we like it if questions asked deal with [specific solvable questions that you face as a developer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). After attaining 20 rep you are welcome to discuss this question in our chatroom, and if you chose to edit the question to provide more detail it may be re-opened.

Comment: Think primarily about budget. Also: how well does it work with your game system (eg. unity + blender + bones)? Can you hire/learn it? These would be the main ones I look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a vague question. But still.

Choosing 3d modeling software is personal thing. There are number of softwares available and many of them have big number of features. So you should try demo of every one of them, try to model something more then simple, and whichever "clicks" is the one for you. Except for the price feature.

You have popular max and maya but are pretty expensive.
you have as good houdini (with good free version, 'apprentice') and XSI (which is as good and cost less then max and maya and from personal experience has best workflow of all)

and there is free blender for which also has all the "big" features, and is **free**. But it's UI IMHO is unintuitive. But it's free.